# How can I load multiple levels when lazy loading in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, relational-database, lazy-loading

I have a program using C# / WPF and SQL Server with EF Core 5. Sometimes I use eager loading, for example:

```
(from r in MyContext.Refractions where r.Id == id select r)
    .Include(r => r.RightLens)
    .ThenInclude(l => l.Prisms);
```

and so on. This is a database of optical data, hence the field names. `Refractions` are linked to (eye) `Examinations`.

When I want to lazy load, I use the following:

```
MyContext.Entry(patient)
         .Collection(e => e.Examinations).Load();
```

My question is, when using the second, lazy option, is there a way to also load associated data (the equivalent of `.Include` for the `Load` method)?

So for example, I want the equivalent of:

```
MyContext.Entry(patient)
         .Collection(e => e.Examinations)
         .Load().Include(r => r.Refractions);
```

or do I need to detect that the `Refractions` collection is not loaded somewhere in my view model and then load it manually when required?

Comment: It is not lazy load. It is explicit load. You have to configure context for Lazy load and make collection properties `virtual` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-with-proxies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't think this is possible yet, you could write some methods like those:

```
public IEagerLoadedQueryable<E, P> LoadRelated<E, P>(IQueryable<E> query, Expression<Func<E, P>> navProperty) where E : class {
  var q= query.Include(navProperty);
  return new EagerLoadedQueryable<E, P>(q);
}

public IEagerLoadedQueryable<E, Prop> ThenLoadRelated<E, Prev, Prop>(IEagerLoadedQueryable<E, IEnumerable<Prev>> query, Expression<Func<Prev, Prop>> navProperty) where E : class {
  var q= (IIncludableQueryable<E, IEnumerable<Prev>>)query;
  return new EagerLoadedQueryable<E, Prop>(q.ThenInclude(navProperty));
}


public IEagerLoadedQueryable<E, Prop> ThenLoadRelated<E, Prev, Prop>(IEagerLoadedQueryable<E, Prev> query, Expression<Func<Prev, Prop>> navProperty) where E : class {
  var q= (IIncludableQueryable<E, Prev>)query;
  return new EagerLoadedQueryable<E, Prop>(q.ThenInclude(navProperty));
}
```